# Try to delete files used by IIS

Tags: windows, io, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I got a service coded in c# whoes deleted somes web site files hosted on iis, before an update. But sometime when i delete the files, they stay there.

If I try to delete them manually, via explorer, the file are not deletable, because they are in state "Delete pending".

There is the way my service try to delete the file

```
 try
                {
                  // Enlève tout les attributs sur le fichiers afin de s'assurer que le fichier n'est pas en lecture seul
                  File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);

                  // Supprime le fichier
                  File.Delete(file);
}
```

It's there a way to avoid this state ?

What can i do to force the delete by c# code?

Could i release all process to the file by c# code  ?

The environnement is

IIS 7.5
Windows 2008-r2
.net 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Why close my question ?

Comment: I think it will be probably moved on serverfault

Comment: And now is it better ?

Comment: It's could be nice people try to close the questions say why they wont see my question be close.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to find out what other process has the files open. I don't know how you'd do that programatically, but speaking as a sysadmin, the handle.exe utility from SysInternals (or their Process Explorer GUI tool) can show that to you real-time.

Then you'll want to either:

1. Avoid the condition that causes the file to be locked by the other process,
2. Close the handle if you can do so safely.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the question was how to do it programatically. I really do not understand why my question was migrated to server fault.

Comment: Too bad; I have no idea why the folks on SO would have voted to move it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of files that are on that state through [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960241.aspx)
I don't know how your files end up in that state but the first way that comes to my mind
is to rename and then delete the file there is a similar solution for C++ on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764072/c-win32-how-to-wait-for-a-pending-delete-to-complete/3764298#3764298)

In C# it should be something like

```
File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
File.Delete(newFileName);
```

Comment: You think the move will unlock the file ?

Comment: It renames the file.